# C++ different values in local function vs main function

Tags: c++, vector, file-io, integer, program-entry-point

I'm trying to write a function that parses a file including a 2d array size 2x2 (first line of file has the first row, second line has the second row) then an empty space, then values to be put in a vector, then an empty space, then an integer value.

I was able to read the values in and verify within the local function that the right data is coming in.. but when I try to print some of the values in my main function, the integer value is always showing up as 0, and the value from the vector I'm trying to print does not show up in the output stream at all and the program just terminates.. The 2d array value has no issues in the main function or in the local function, just the integer and vector values.

Here is an example of my input file:

```
-2.000 5.003
3.020 8.000

2.000
5.005
1.000
6.500
4.000
1.008
7.000
3.009

4
```

And a copy of the code I am having issues with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

double arr_2x2[2][2];
vector<double> input_vector;
int input_int = 0;

void parse_input_file(string file_in, double arr_2x2[2][2], vector<double> input_vector, int input_int ){

  fstream infile;
  int empty_line = 0;
  infile.open (file_in, ios::in);
  if (infile.is_open()){   //checking whether the file is open
      string tp;
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
        /* first two lines include the 2d array values */
        
          getline(infile, tp, ' ');
          //cout << tp << "\n";
          arr_2x2[i][0] = stod(tp);
          getline(infile, tp);
          //cout << tp << "\n";
          arr_2x2[i][1] = stod(tp);
      }
      //empty line.. throw it out
      getline(infile, tp);
      while(getline(infile, tp)){ //read data from file object and put it into string.
          if(!tp.size()){//if there is an empty line assert a flag
            empty_line = 1;
          }else{
            if(empty_line == 1){
              input_int = stoi(tp);//empty line asserted so int value
            }else{
              input_vector.push_back(stod(tp));
            }
          }

      }  
      infile.close();
      printf("matrix value: %.3lf\n",arr_2x2[0][0]);
      printf("vector value: %.3lf\n",input_vector[1]);
      printf("integer value: %d\n",input_int);
  }



}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  string file_in  = string(argv[2]);
  parse_input_file(file_in, arr_2x2, input_vector, input_int);
  printf("matrix value: %.3lf\n",arr_2x2[0][0]);
  printf("integer value: %d\n",input_int);
  printf("vector value: %.3lf\n",input_vector[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the actual output in your question?

Comment: The parameter `vector<double> input_vector` should be passed by reference. Otherwise, no changes within `parse_input_file` will be reflected back in `main`

Comment: None of the global variables should be global. Instead these should be local variables in `int main()` passed by reference to the parse_input_file () function

Answer (score 2):

```
double arr_2x2[2][2];
vector<double> input_vector;
```

The shown code first declares `arr_2x2` and `input_vectors` in global scope. Global scope means that these objects are accessible in every function, without having to pass them as parameters.

```
void parse_input_file(string file_in, double arr_2x2[2][2], vector<double> input_vector, int input_int ){
```

The shown code then declares a `parse_input_file` function. Two of its parameters have the exact same names as global objects. This always leads to confusion, and hard to identify bugs. If the intent is to pass the two global objects here as parameters to this function, this will accomplish absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever, except to create confusion. `arr_2x2` and `input_vector` are already global. Every function can access them. Passing them as parameters is not needed.

```
parse_input_file(file_in, arr_2x2, input_vector, input_int);
```

Predictably, `main()` calls this function and passes the two global objects by value, creating this confusion. `input_vector` gets passed by value, as I already mentioned. This means, effectively, that the function gets a duplicate copy of the global object (because that's what passing by value means). Any changes the function makes to what it knows as na `input_vector` will mysteriously disappear when the function returns, and won't appear in the global object.

As best practice: don't name parameters to functions with the same name as global objects. And when you do need to pass non-global objects to functions as parameters you need to fully understand the differences between passing them by value or by reference, see your C++ textbook for more information.